# Making an object appear at a certain frame by python

Tags: python, animation, objects

Blender 2.83

I would like to have objects 'spawn' when a certain frame has been reached, and to do this, I'm having the cube too small to see until the frame I want it to appear, and then it'll in one frame scale to the appropriate size. I thought the following would work:

For the frame `my_frame` the object `cube` is meant to start to exist, I apply:

```
        cube.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.01, 0.01, 0.01))
        cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="scale",frame = 0)
        cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="scale",frame = 3*my_frame)
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(100, 100, 100))
        cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="scale",frame = 3*my_frame+3)
        cube.select_set(False)
```

(Note that time in my animation moves forwards in 3's, that's why it's 3*my_frame)

So the cube should have a keyframe at the start, and just before it spawns making it miniscule, and then during `3*my_frame` to `3*my_frame+3` it should grow 100-fold, so it looks like it instantly appears. Instead, it starts growing from being tiny at frame 0, until it's full size at `my_frame` - which makes me feel like the 4th line above is being ignored. What am I doing wrong?

What's an alternative approach? (I could repeat the above with data_path = "location" and teleport the object in too, but I imagine I'll have the same issue.)

---

In the comments it's suggested to do something like the following:

```
    obj.hide_render = True
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path = "hide_render",frame = 30)
    obj.hide_render = False
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path = "hide_render",frame = 60)
    obj.hide_render = True
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path = "hide_render",frame = 90)
```

Which does hide obj in the render mode, but I would also like it to be hidden in the standard animation mode, which it doesn't seem to be. I want this since it's easier to move the camera as desired, while recording that part of the screen from another window. Also, having things scale rapidly looks good in my simulation, since it corresponds to creatures disappearing, it looks good to have them disappear rapidly, but not instantly.

Comment: So for my_frame = 10 for example, I would expect inserting scale-keyframes at 0 and 30 would force its size to remain fixed from 0 to 30, and then from 30 to 33 it would grow 100-fold. But instead it grows 100-fold from 0 to 30.

Comment: First of all if you want visibility of the object animated, why don't you animate visibility instead of scale?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Well, I imagine the same problem would occur. I could instead insert keyframes at `0,3*my_frame`, and `3*my_frame+3` for the material by `matnode_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs[i].keyframe_insert("default_value",frame = appropriate_frame)`

For whichever `i` is the appropriate one for making the material transparent, but then I imagine the object will just start transparent, and gradually become non-transparent until `3*my_frame`

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Or is there another way to change visibility than modifying the principled bsdf node?

Comment: You can use `object.hide_render`

Comment: I guess in 2.8 that's bpy.types.Object.hide_set, but I don't see how to keyframe that

Comment: `cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render",frame = 3*my_frame)` sets the keyframe. But I think you would need the value updated at that frame, so you need to move to that frame and that updates the scene, so it might get slow and inefficient. I have no experience with this that's why I hesitate to write an answer, but I think it's possible to construct fcurves with Python without updating all the scene when the current frame is changed. But it makes no sense to animate scale when you need to animate visibility.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Okay, I've tried your method, and it does work in the render mode. But my scale approach would show up nicely in the animation mode, without having to actually render (which is nice for being able to maneuver my viewpoint around - simulation is what I'm interested in animating)

I mean to say that although it works in render mode, it doesn't work if you just run the animation from the animation tab, even with the 'viewport shading' button clicked

Comment: There is also `hide_viewport`. Animating scale for visibility might result in undesired behaviour - for example, if you use motion blur, animated scale might be considered for it and your object might get blurry because of abrupt changes in scale. If your script is going to be used in various scenarios, it might be best to stick with things designed for the functionality by default. But... I don't think it's a big deal.

Comment: Good point, thanks @MartynasŽiemys